# Can an "unlinked" memory in QNX be freed

Tags: c++, memory, qnx

I am developing a program, which is dealing with some graphics rendering. I am using a 3rd. party library for the rendering so all I do is to create objects and request their rendering from the library. The loading and freeing of resources like textures and fonts is done by that library. My program is running on QNX 7.

My problem is that after I run the program for some time (which is not that much) I am seeing that the memory, used by the process is growing quite fast, which is not OK. In my program I am changing the graphics content a lot, which causes the program to load new images and fonts and unload those, which are not used currently. All this processing is done by the code from the third-party library and I can put my own code to see that allocated memory is freed - the library I am talking about has methods which display how much CPU and GPU memory is used and also has methods to free the memory. I am able to display the currently used memory, call the method to free the memory and then again print the used memory. I see that the used memory has dropped, which is what I expect.

I use the **pidin mem** command to display the used memory from each process. I am able to see that my process cleans some memory when I call the 3rd. party library function. However, it is not able to clean enough memory.

What I saw in the **pidin mem** output are lots of blocks, which are named as "**unlinked**". Below is part of the output I've got from **pidin**:

```
163879   1 MyGraphApp  12r SIGWAITINFO         0  175M   32K(516K)*
           libm.so.3          @ b52a000              96K  4096
           libstdc++.so.6     @ b544000            1044K  4096
           libsocket.so.3     @ b716000             124K  4096
           **unlinked**       @24d90000 (       0)       2048K
           **unlinked**       @24f90000 (       0)        128K
           **unlinked**       @24fb0000 (       0)        128K
           **unlinked**       @24fd0000 (  210000)         64K
           **unlinked**       @24fe0000 (       0)        128K
           **unlinked**       @25000000 (       0)        128K
           **unlinked**       @25020000 (  21f000)        4096
           **unlinked**       @25021000 (  21f000)         36K
           **unlinked**       @2502a000 (       0)       5400K
           **unlinked**       @25570000 (  235000)       6164K
           **unlinked**       @25b75000 (  227000)         28K
           **unlinked**       @25b7c000 (  22d000)        8192
           **unlinked**       @25b7e000 (       0)        128K
           **unlinked**       @25b9e000 (       0)        128K
           **unlinked**       @25bbe000 (  840000)         60K
           **unlinked**       @25bcd000 (  22e000)        4096
           **unlinked**       @25bce000 (  850000)       5804K
           **unlinked**       @26179000 (  22e000)         28K
```

As you can see my application uses 175MB of memory. When I start the application in the beginning this memory is below 100MB. I see that the only part, which is growing are these "**unlinked**" blocks.

What is this "**unlinked**" memory? My understanding is that this is memory, which has been deallocated but it is not returned to the OS. Is my understanding correct?

Most importantly - can I free the memory marked as "**unlinked**"? Who is responsible to do this - my application and probably the code from the third-party library or the OS itself? Any information regarding this issue and how it might be fixed will be highly appreciated.

PS: I want to mention that the 3rd. party library and my application are developed using C++.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Being unlinked means that it is no longer available to be opened by name using shm_open. However, any memory mappings (mmap) or file descriptors (shm_open) that still exist relating to that object will prevent it from being actually freed.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what is still related to the unlinked memory?